# Multiple Bandgaps

Tags: solid-state-physics

I'm going through solid state physics' models chronologically and I've reached the Bloch theory, which is after Sommerfeld's quantum mechanical version of the Drude model with an added infinitely deep potential (particle in a box problem). Bloch then adds a periodic potential created by the fixed ions, i.e. nucleii of the solid. Mathematically, various bands are obtained. Up to this point I only knew about the conduction and valence bands and the respective gap between them. What are these other bands and gaps?

Answer (score 1):

Those other (lower) bands will be filled.  The most interesting bands are the ones that are only just barely full, or only partially filled, as well as the empty bands just above the filled ones. Usually when people speak of the band gap, they mean between the highest filled band and the lowest empty band.

Comment: Which one is the valence and which one is the conduction band?

Comment: Rule of thumb. The band below the fermi level is the valence band, the band above is the conduction band.

Comment: For an insulating material the chemical potential will be in between bands (not within a band as for a conductor). All the bands below the chemical potential will be full, all the bands above the chemical potential will be empty. The "valence" band/bands is/are the full band/bands closest to the chemical potential. The "conduction" bands/bands is/are the empty band/bands closest to the chemical potential.